# How to merge two custom types list in C#

Tags: c#

I have two List, How can i merge or combine them.

first list similar to this one :

```
dateList = [{01/10/2018, 02/10/2018, 03/10/2018, 04/10/2018, 05/10/2018, 06/10/2018}]
```

second List similar to this one :

```
markStatus = [{01/10/2018, true}, {03/10/2018, true}, {05/10/2018, false }]
```

I want the result to be like :

```
result = `[{01/10/2018, true}, {2/10/2018, false}, {03/10/2018, true}, {04/10/2018, false}, {05/10/2018, false}, {06/10/2018, false}]
```

Comment: create a simple class and loop through all the items adding them to a collection (like List<>) and then serialize that list to json.

Comment: This is not valid C#

Comment: It's easier to understand (and answer) if you use valid c#...otherwise we're just guessing. Please show a simple, compile-able sample that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] dateList = { "01/10/2018", "02/10/2018", "03/10/2018", "04/10/2018", "05/10/2018", "06/10/2018" };
            Dictionary<string, bool> markStatus = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
            {
                {"01/10/2018",true } ,
                {"03/10/2018",true },
                {"05/10/2018",false }
            };

            Dictionary<string, bool> result = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

            bool flag;

            foreach (var item in dateList)
            {
                flag = false;
                foreach (var key in markStatus.Keys)
                {
                    if (item.Equals(key))
                    {
                        result.Add(item, markStatus[key]);
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!flag)
                {
                    result.Add(item, false);
                }
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If the data type is not a string Array or Dictionary, you can do it the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Having to guess at some property names here:

```
dateList.Select(d => (d, markStatus.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Date == d)?.Select(s => s.Status) ?? false));
```